# Flush only certain entities in single transaction

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-odm, dbal

in my application I do write to a read model table (think CQRS) at certain times. While doing so, I also have to remove older read models. So at any given point I need to:

1. Remove entities a,b,c
2. Persist entities x,y,z

In order to maintain a valid read model throughout the lifecycle, I would like to encapsulate this process in a single transaction. [Doctrine does provide the necessary means](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html).

However, I also must guarantee that no other entities are being flushed in the process. Sadly, calling doctrine's `$em->getConnection()->commit();` seems to to flush the whole unit of work. But according to the docs I have to call that to finalise my transaction.

I cannot introduce a second entity manager to only take of my read model entities as they are in the same namespace as the other entities and apparently that is not the way the doctrine-orm-bundle is supposed to be used.

The only other approach I see is to work on a lower level and circumvent the EntityManager and UnitOfWork completely, but I would like to guarantee transactional integrity and do not see a way to do so without em/ouw.

Comment: You could try detaching the objects (`->detach($entity)`), flushing and then re-attaching (through (`->merge($entity)`) and then starting your transaction.

Comment: You can control which entites will be checked for changes with [tracking policies](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html). You could first persist read models and flush them, later other entites and call flush another time.

Comment: @malarzm : I don't think this is a feasible approach, as the write model can potentially be (re-)created anywhere in the lifecycle. Thus, I cannot guarantee that no other entity has been persisted yet (or even modified and therefore marked for flush by doctrine)

Comment: @ccKep : I had the same idea, though I feel like detaching and re-attaching everything in the UOW seems like a major interference in the UOW and rather fragile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: The way your application works might warrant that update-concerns are completely separable into two **independent** sets, but that's unusual, and fragile (usually not even true at the time of making the assertion). The proper way to model that is using separate EntityManagers for each of the sets, and by manually guarding their interconnections is the semantics of "how they are independent" coded into the system.

Details:

If I understand the question correctly, you are facing a design flaw here. You have two sets of updates (one for the read models and one for the other entities) and you mix them (because you want both in the same entity manager) while you also want to separate them (by the means of a separate transaction). In general, this won't work.

For example, let's think non-read-model entity instance A is just created in-memory (so it has no ID yet) and based on this you decide to reference it with read-model entity instance R. The R->A relationship is valid in memory, but now you expect to be able to flush only read model entities but not others. I.e. when you try to persist+flush R it will reference a non-existing foreign key and your RDBMS will hopefully fail the transaction. On a high-level, this is because a connected in-memory graph should be consistent data in its **entirety** and when you try to split its valid changes into subsets, you're rearranging the order of those changes implicitly, which may introduce temporary inconsistency, and then your transaction commit might just be at such a point.

Of course, it may happen that you know some rule why such a thing will never happen and why consistent state of each set is warranted in a fashion that is completely independent from the other set. But then you need to write your code reflecting that separation; the way you can do that is to **use two entity managers**. In that case your code will clearly cope with the two distinct transactions, their separation and how exactly that is consistent from both sides. But even in this case, to avoid clashes of updates, you probably need to have rules outlining a one-way visibility between the two sets, which will also imply an order to committing transactions. This is because transactions in a connected graph can be nested, but not "only overlap", because at each transaction commit you are asking the ORM to sync the *consistent* in-memory data of the transaction scope to the RDBMS.

I know you mentioned that you do not want to use two EMs, because read-model entities "are in the same namespace as the other entities and apparently that is not the way the doctrine-orm-bundle is supposed to be used".

1. The namespace does not really matter. You can use them separately in the two managers. You can even interconnect them, if you a) properly merge() them and b) cater for the above mentioned consistency you need to provide for both EM's transactions (because now they are working on *one* connected graph).
2. You should elaborate what exactly you refer to by saying "that is not the way the doctrine-orm-bundle is supposed to be used" -- probably there's an error in the original suggestion or something wrong with the way that suggestion is applied to this problem.